# Clear and re-draw using svg.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I want to draw some elements using svg.js then clear the canvas and draw new elements. I'm using [draw.clear()](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/referencing-creating-elements/#clear) but when I re-draw the elements, they aren't visible. Is this approach correct or am I missing something? I also tried [remove()](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/manipulating/#remove).

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var pos_x = 0;
var pos_y = 0;

var texto = [];
var grupo = [];
var rect = [];
var clip = [];
var random_rotation = [];

var latino = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'.split('');
var cirilico = 'АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЬЮЯ'.split('');
var hebreo = 'אבגדהוזיךכל   םמןנסעףפפצקחט   '.split('');
var griego = 'ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨ'.split('');
var arabe = 'ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةءأإ'.split('');
var coreano = 'ㅏㅑㅓㅕㅗㅛㅜㅠㅡㅣㅐㅒㅔㅖㅘㅙㅚㅝㅞㅟㅢㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎㄲㄸㅃㅆㅉㄳㄵㄶㄺㄻㄿㄽㄾㄿㅀㅄ'.split('');
var glagolitico = 'ⰀⰁⰂⰃⰄⰅⰆⰇⰈⰉⰊⰋⰌⰍⰎⰏⰐⰑⰒⰓⰔⰕⰖⰗⰘⰙⰚⰛⰜⰝⰞⰟⰠⰡⰢⰣⰤⰥⰦⰧⰨⰩⰪⰫⰬⰭⰮ'.split('');
var hiragana = 'あかさたなはまやらわがざだばぱいきしちにひみり(ゐ)ぎじぢびぴうくすつぬふむゆるぐずづぶぷえけせてねへめれ(ゑ)げぜでべぺおこそとのほもよろをごぞどぼぽ'.split('');
var katakana = 'アカサタナハマヤラワガザダバパヴァイキシチニヒミリ(ヰ)ギジヂビピヴィウクスツヌフムユルグズヅブプヴエケセテネヘメレ(ヱ)ゲゼデベペヴェオコソトノホモヨロヲゴゾドボポヴォ'.split('');

var sistemas = [latino, cirilico, hebreo, griego, arabe, coreano, glagolitico, hiragana, katakana];

var alfabeto = [];
var letra = [];

var draw = SVG().addTo('.container').size(width, height).attr({id: 'svg'}); 

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRndFloat(min, max) {
  return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

// Create symbols
function grafema(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){

        alfabeto[i] = getRndInteger(0, sistemas.length - 1);

        letra[i] = sistemas[alfabeto[i]][getRndInteger(0, sistemas[alfabeto[i]].length - 1)];

        random_rotation[i] = getRndInteger(0, 360);

        texto[i] = draw.text(letra[i])
                    .font({
                        family: 'Arial Unicode MS',
                        size: 500,
                        anchor: 'middle'
                    })
                    .transform({
                        translateX: width/2,
                        translateY: (height/2) * -1,
                        rotate: random_rotation[i],
                        scale: getRndFloat(0.5, 0.6)
                    });

        grupo[i] = draw.group()
                    .attr({
                        id: 'letra ' + i
                    });

        grupo[i].add(texto[i]);

        rect[i] = draw.rect(200, 200)
                    .attr({
                        x: pos_x,
                        y: pos_y,
                    })
                    .transform({
                        rotate : random_rotation[i],
                    });

        pos_x = pos_x + 200;

        if (pos_x > 200) {
            pos_x = 0;
            pos_y = pos_y + 200;
        }

        clip[i] = draw.clip().add(rect[i]);
        grupo[i].clipWith(clip[i]);
    }
}

grafema();
draw.clear();
grafema();
```

This is a simplified version of a program I'm trying to create. In the future I would like to clear and re-draw whenever the user makes a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is not the `clear()` method. You are using global variables `pos_x` and `pos_y` and you are incrementing them. In your second drawing, the images are outside the visible area. To solve your issue, initialise those variables in the beginning of your `grafema` function:

```js
// ...
function grafema() {
    pos_x = 0;
    pos_y = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        // ...
```

Example of execution with infinite drawings:

https://jsbin.com/mehuholiwo/edit?js,output